# how to use shopify api php

Tags: php, json, xml, shopify

Hey i am new in shopify and i have create new private app in my store.i want to use shopify api in my php program.i have write following code in my php file.

Code:

```
<?php
    $API_KEY = 'XXX';
    $SECRET = 'XXX';
    $STORE_URL = 'XXX';
    $PRODUCT_ID = 'XXX';

    $url = 'https://' . $API_KEY . ':' . md5($SECRET) . '@' . $STORE_URL . '/admin/products/' . $PRODUCT_ID . '.xml';

    $session = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml', 'Content-Type: application/xml'));

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
    $product_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response); 
    echo $product_xml->title;
    echo $product_xml->variants->variant->{'inventory-quantity'};
?>
```

i got the following error.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in index.php on line 24

Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in C:\wamp\www\apis\index.php on line 24

please help me to short out this problem as soon as possible.please please...
thanks in advance.

Comment: I think header should be set as application/json instead of application/xml

Comment: i try application/json but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($data );
```

Use the above code.

Shopify returns the data in the JSON format, so decode it and use it for your purpose.

Also make sure that the URL that you are using is correct by loading it in the browser.